# Why does my EC2 instance invariably always show a 20.1% steal percentage when I issue the top command?

Tags: amazon-ec2, top-command

It quickly jumps down to 0%, but I am curious as to why it claims 20.1% steal literally every time I enter `top`. Try it yourself... `top`, `q`, `top`, `q`, `top`, `q`... it never fails.

Is it actually 20.1% steal or is this a bug with the `top` command?

This is happening on my t2.small instance running ubuntu.

Comment: You dont need to run multiple times the top command, you can do:
top, press "s", write "0.5", enter. It is going to refresh every 0.5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

In EC2, you don't get exclusive access to the CPU core, instead its shared between several instances. Steal time measures the amount of time that your instance is waiting for CPU time.

In either case, there is a bit of processing needed when when you start `top`. With a small instance, that may be enough to force you to wait for CPU to be available to you.